# Use SQL regex (LIKE) in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using SQL in pgadmin4 (Postgres).
I query a list of IP's and occurences of the IP's. If it matches the regex I want to print the regex and the sum of occurences.

I'm querying the following:

```
select distinct dstaddress, _col1 from test where _col1 > 1 AND 
dstaddress LIKE '10.228.55.%' OR 
dstaddress LIKE '10.228.9.%' 
group by dstaddress, _col1
```

And this gives me as output the IP and its occurences:

```
"10.228.55.17"  365942
"10.228.9.104"  8
"10.228.9.105"  4
"10.228.9.106"  2
"10.228.9.107"  8
"10.228.9.108"  10
"10.228.9.109"  434
"10.228.9.110"  127
```

But as output I want to have the regex and the sum of occurences:

```
"10.228.55.%"   365942
"10.228.9.%"    593
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select v.pat, sum(t._col1)
from (values ('10.228.55.%'), ('10.228.9.%')) v(pat) left join
     test t
     on t._col1 > 1 and
        t.dstaddress like v.pat
group by v.pat;
```

Note:  "occurrences" appears to be `_col1`.  You would, of course, use whatever the appropriate column is, if that is not the case.

This puts the patterns in the derived table.  They can then be used for the aggregation, without having to repeat them (a source of errors in the query).